# Calculator for pi stopping

Tags: c, performance

I'm trying to calculate pi with the precision of 10 decimal places. And the efficiency has to be the best(speed and memory allocation). The programming language is C in CodeBlocks.

I don't want to change the formula I'm using: [image]

**Problem**: after a while, the resulting number stops incrementing but the iteration doesn't stop.

I'm not sure if this is a math problem or some kind of variable overflow.

The resulting number is **3.1415926431** and the number I want to achieve is 3.1415926535.
Every time the incrementation stops at this specific number and the iteration continues. Is there a possibility of an overflow or something?

Now I'm printing out every thousandth iteration (just the see the process) This will be deleted in the end.

notice the
 `a = n; a *= 4 * a;` is for memory efficiency, there are more similar cuts I did.

code I'm using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int n=1;
    double resultNumber= 1;
    double pi = 3.1415926535;
    double pi2 = pi / 2;
    double a;
    while(1){
        a = n;
        a *= 4 * a;
        resultNumber *= a / (a - 1);
        n++;

        if (fabs(resultNumber - pi2) < pow(10,-10))
            break;

        if (n%1000==0) {
            printf("%.10f %d\n", resultNumber*2, n);
        }
    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it out here:
https://onlinegdb.com/q2Gil1DHdy

Comment: Use "long double" or similar. There are also libraries for arbitrary precision floating numbers.

Comment: If you don't want to change the formula you are using, you are not going to get maximal efficiency.

Comment: Willing the best efficiency while using a completely inefficient and inaccurate formula seems a weird goal.

Comment: You're not the first one who thinks about this problem. There is lots of working code out there available with an easy search.

Comment: Floating-point types like `double` provide an approximate, *imperfect* simulation of real numbers.  But most infinite series, including the one you show, have infinitely-large or infinitely-small terms which work properly (can be evaluated accurately and correctly) *only* in terms of true real numbers.   In particular, no finite-precision floating-pont type can reliably compute 4n² / (4n²-1) for large n.  You are either going to have to use a different formula, or an multiple-precision arithmetic library of some sort.

Comment: In what way does `a = n; a *= 4 * a;` improve memory efficiency ???

Comment: Re “I'm trying to calculate pi with the precision of 10 decimal places”: Sigh. π ≈ 2.0000000000 + 1.0000000000 = 3.0000000000 is a calculation of π with a precision of 10 decimal places. Would you like some accuracy along with that precision?

Comment: _Side note:_ You're doing `pow(10,-10)` _inside_ your loop. This is slow. Better to do `double lim = pow(10,-10);` _above_ the loop. Then, change the `if` to use `lim`

Comment: compute products of 2n/(n+1) and 2n/(n-1) separately and multiply as the last step, this allows for a slightly greater accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility of an overflow or something?

The precision of floating-point numbers is limited.  In a typical C implementation, `double` has 53 bits of mantissa, which corresponds to about 15 significant decimal digits.  But the range of such FP numbers is much larger than +/- 10<sup>15</sup>, so when your FP number is large enough, the units digit is not significant.  Then subtracting 1 from it will not produce a different number.  When your `a` reaches that point, the quotient `a / (a - 1)` will be identically 1, so multiplying by that will not change the working result.

It's possible that you would get enough additional precision by using `long double` instead of `double`.  That might help both in getting you more terms in your product before the problem described above sets in, and also by reducing the relative magnitude of FP rounding errors earlier in the computation.

Comment: Willing the best efficiency while using a completely inefficient and inaccurate formula seems a weird goal.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to comment here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is there a way of making the a / (a - 1) valid for such large(small) numbers??

Comment: @YvesDaoust take it as: how to achieve the best efficiency using this formula

Comment: @Miggo, as I said, you might rescue this particular program by using `long double` instead of `double`.  Alternatively, you might switch to an arbitrary precision numeric library such as GMP.  But ultimately, most rational numbers cannot be exactly represented in computer memory, so no matter what, you have to deal with limited precision at some point, in some way.

Comment: @Miggo: what do you call *best* ? Your method might be the fastest, but delivers a mediocre result.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My method isn't the best(fastest) for now, my problem is getting to the final result at all

Comment: You don't get it. I said it is already the best. And unusable.

Comment: Again, @Miggo, for the formula you are using to produce a result accurate to the precision you are trying to achieve, you need to use higher-precision arithmetic and numeric representations than you are presently using.  You are getting close enough now that it is plausible that switching to `long double` would be sufficient.  But if that turns out not to be sufficient, and you are unwilling to use a different formula, then the next step would be to engage an arbitrary-precision math library.

Answer (score 1):

You can rescue a little of the accuracy by the following trick:

```
4n² / (4n² - 1) = 1 + 1 / (4n² - 1)
```

For large n, these factors are close to 1 and challenge the floating-point representation. You can use the identity

```
(1 + a)(1 + b)(1 + c)... = 1 + (a + b + c...) + (ab + ac + ... + bc + ...) ...
```

So for small terms a, b, c... (when the second order terms disappear), it is more accurate to use the approximation `1 + (a + b + c...)`, of course summing inside the parenthesis first.